# Folder Upload to web app

Tags: javascript, upload, directory

First off, I understand that this question has been asked before but they all have been asked 6 months + ago and often refer to the Filesystem API which should now be considered dead.

(SOURCE: http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/NOTE-file-system-api-20140424/)

I am wondering if it is possible to upload a folder, or multiple folders to a web app similar to how a file upload works with JavaScript.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have two options for a non-Flash, non-Java solution.  I'm going to assume you are looking for JS only based on your question's tags.

1. DnD via Filesystem API - Chrome/Opera only. Future unknown even in these browsers.
2. `<input type="file" webkitdirectory>` - Chrome/Opera only.  Not part of any spec, synchronous operation so the UI thread may be noticeably blocked for large folders or high-latency file systems (use at your own risk).